# Creating Hamburger Nav From Spans: Hamburger not visible

Tags: html, css

New to this and creating a hamburger menu for the first time. Our teacher wants us to do it with spans. However, it doesn't seem to be working when I view the site at the corresponding breakpoint. It should be appearing in the upper right hand corner. I have googled this and found some amazing solutions using toggle as a alt way to create an animate hamburger menus. I also used inspect element and can't seem to find it there either. But I'd like to make this work the way she outlined. Any light you could shed on this would be amazing! Thanks in advance.

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <!-- link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css"> Commented Out As Per In Clas TA Fix-->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:700,700italic|Oswald:700|Source+Sans+Pro:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Startup Matchmaker</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Startup Matchmaker"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="love, startup, matching"/>
    <meta name="author" content="Chantel Zapata"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>

<!-- HEADER -->
<header>
    <h1>Startup Matchmaker</h1>
    <div class="hamburger">
        <span class="burgerlines"></span>
        <span class="burgerlines"></span>
        <span class="burgerlines"></span>
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="main-nav"><a class="main-item" href="developers/developers.html">DEVELOPERS</a></li>
            <li class="main-nav"><a class="main-item" href="designers/designers.html">DESIGNERS</a></li>
            <li class="main-nav"><a class="secondary-item" href="howitworks/howitworks.html">How It Works</a></li>
            <li class="main-nav"><a class="secondary-item" href="ourteam/ourteam.html">Our Team</a></li>
            <li class="main-nav"><a class="secondary-item" href="blog/blog.html">Blog<a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>

<!-- QUOTE -->
<div class="quote">
    <h2>Because two brains <del class="quote-taste">taste</del><span> </span><ins class="quote-are">are</ins> better than one.</h2>
</div>

<!-- MAIN AREA -->
<div class="main-image">
    <div class="translucent-container">
        <h3>Meet Your Match!</h3>
        <p class="container-para">Have a great idea for your product, but need help making it a reality? We're here to help. Startup Matchmaker is the best place for designers and developers to find each other.</p>
        <button class="live-button" href="#">CREATE A PROFILE</button>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- PROMO TOUTS -->
<div class="all-promo-touts">
<div class="promo-tout fl">
    <h4>Create a Profile</h4>
    <p>Are you a Designer? Developer? Put yourself out there so that others can find you!</p>
    <button class="gray-button" href="#" id="signuppop">SIGN UP NOW</button>
</div>
<div class="vertical-line fl">
</div>
<div class="promo-tout fl">
    <h4>Find a Developer</h4>
    <p>Are you a Designer? Developer? Put yourself out there so that others can find you!</p>
    <button class="gray-button" href="#">START YOUR SEARCH</button>
</div>
<div class="vertical-line fl">
</div>
<div class="promo-tout-last fr">
    <h4>Find a Designer</h4>
    <p>Are you a Designer? Developer? Put yourself out there so that others can find you!</p>
    <button class="gray-button" href="#">START YOUR SEARCH</button>
</div>
</div>

<!-- FOOTER -->
<footer>
    <p class="footer-text .clearfix:after">&copy; 2013 Startup Matchmaker. Made in NY.</p>
</footer>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('signuppop').onclick = function(){
        window.alert("Not taking sign ups yet. Sorry.");
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
/* FONT REF
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, sans-serif;
font-family: 'Oswald', Arial, sans-serif;
font-family: 'Merriweather', 'Times New Roman', serif; */

.clearfix:after {
     content: ".";
     display: block;
     clear: both;
     visibility: hidden;
     line-height: 0;
     height: 0;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
.fl {
    float: left;
}
.fr {
    float: right;
}
* {
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firexfox */
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome/iOS/Android */
     box-sizing: border-box; /* IE */
}
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 60px;
}

/* Header */
header {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fdf731;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Merriweather', 'Times New Roman', serif;
    font-size: 0.5em;
    color: #fdf731;
    float: left;
    margin: 4%;
}

nav {
    margin-right: 4%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    float: right;
}

.hamburger {
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:767px){
    .hamburger {
    margin-right: 4%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    float: right;
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
    }
    .burgerlines {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    }
}

.main-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
}

.main-item {
    font-family: 'Oswald', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.3em;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.main-item:hover {
    font-family: 'Oswald', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.3em;
    color: #fdf731;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.main-item:active {
    font-family: 'Oswald', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.3em;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #c6c6c6;
}
.secondary-item {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.3em;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.secondary-item:hover {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.3em;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:767px){
    .main-nav {
        display: none;
    }
}

/* Footer */
footer {
    background-color: #000;
    height: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    position: initial;
}
.footer-text {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.3333333333333333em;
    margin-left: 4%;
    padding-top: 2%;
}


/* Quote */
.quote {
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #c6c6c6;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
h2 {
    font-family: 'Merriweather', 'Times New Roman', serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.4166666666666667em;
    color: #000;
    padding-top: 2%;
}
.quote-taste {
    font-family: 'Merriweather', 'Times New Roman', serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    text-decoration: line-through;
    padding-top: 2%;
}
.quote-are {
    font-family: 'Merriweather', 'Times New Roman', serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #000;
    padding-top: 2%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fdf731;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Main Area */
.main-image {
    height: 450px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(../images/coworking.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:430px) and (max-width:767px) {
    .main-image {
        height: 600px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:429px){
    .main-image {
        height: 620px;
    }
}

.translucent-container {
    width: 42%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 4%;
    margin-right: 4%;
    padding: 3%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
}

@media only screen and (max-width:767px){
    .translucent-container {
        width: 50%;
        padding: 6%;
    }
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.5em;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    padding: 6% 4% 2% 4%;
}
.container-para {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.3333333333333333em;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    padding: 0 4% 2% 4%;
    line-height: 28px;
    margin-bottom: 4%;
}
.live-button {
    background-color: #fdf731;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;s
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Oswald', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    font-size: 0.3333333333333333em;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px rgba(204, 202, 44, 1);
    border: none;
}

/* Promo Area */
.all-promo-touts {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.promo-tout {
    width: 30%;
}

.promo-tout-last {
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.vertical-line {
    height: 210px;
    width: 2px;
    background-color: #c6c6c6;
    margin-right: 2.15%;
    margin-left: 2.15%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:767px){
    .all-promo-touts {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .promo-tout {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .promo-tout-last {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .vertical-line {
        width: 100%;
        height: 2px;
        margin: 10% 0;
    }
}

h4 {
    font-family: 'Merriweather', 'Times New Roman', serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.4166666666666667em;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 2%;
}
p {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.3333333333333333em;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    line-height: 28px;
    padding-bottom: 4%;
}
.gray-button {
    background-color: #c6c6c6;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Oswald', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    font-size: 0.3333333333333333em;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px rgba(180, 180, 180, 1);
    border: none;
}


/* Coming Soon */
.coming-soon {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10%;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #c6c6c6;
}


/*------------------------------------------------
overflow hidden inital*/

/* Developer Page Boxes */
.dev-boxes {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #c6c6c6;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.dev-single-box {
    height: 419px;
    width: 297px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-top: 4%;
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-bottom: 4%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.interior-box {
    height: 280px;
    width: 280px;
    background-color: #c6c6c6;
    margin-left: 9px;
    margin-top: 9px;
}
.specs {
    font-family: 'Oswald', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.3333333333333333em;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 130px;
}
.some-person {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.3333333333333333em;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    line-height: 28px;
    margin-left: 9px;
    margin-top: 9px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
}

.contact-button {
    background-color: #fdf731;
    padding: 16px 80px 14px 80px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 40px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    font-size: 0.3333333333333333em;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px rgba(204, 202, 44, 1);
}
```

Comment: Suggest you edit the title to get a decent response.Also, specify what you want and exactly where

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on making this more exact. I appreciate it and will keep that level of specificity in mind for any future questions I may have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think first you should remove background color from your ".hamburger" class and than you should try below code.

```
.hamburger span {
      /* hamburger icon */
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 18px;
      height: 2px;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
      vertical-align: middle;
      margin-left: 10px;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-2px);
      -moz-transform: translateY(-2px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-2px);
      -o-transform: translateY(-2px);
      transform: translateY(-2px);
  }
.hamburger span::before, .hamburger span::after {
      content: '';
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: inherit;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
      transition: all 0.2s;
    }
.hamburger span::before {
     top: -6px;
}
.hamburger span::after {
     bottom: -6px;
}
```

Also you have to change your HTML for hamburger menu like below:

```
<div class="hamburger">
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Please find [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jcsr57h9/1/)

I hope this is what you want.
Additionally, You have to attach event to open/close menu.